Почему у меня не распарсивается json?
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, "https://catalog.wb.ru/brands/v2/catalog?ab_testing=false&appType=1&brand=27445&curr=rub&dest=-7886569&sort=popular&spp=30&");
HttpResponseMessage response = await client.SendAsync(request);
response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
var responseBody = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
var item = new Item();
Console.WriteLine(item.name);
List<Item> items = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Item>>($"[{responseBody}]");
items.Sort();
Console.WriteLine(items[0].name);
public class Item
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public int rating { get; set; }
    public string brand { get; set; }
   public int volume { get; set; }
}

Так как content в формате Json, то я хотел распарсить его с помощью Json.Net, но почему-то ничего не выходит.
Пожалуйста, подскажите как правильно это можно оформить?

Внимательно посмотрите на JSON и посмотрите на то, что пишете вы. В JSON {} - это класс, [] - массив, "...": ... - это свойство. Теперь смотрим, вы получаете  JSON, далее непойми зачем оборачиваете его ([{responseBody}]), далее пытаетесь это преобразовать в List<Item>, где у Item есть свойства по типу id, name... Соответствует это с тем, что в JSON? Я вот вижу там класс, внутри которого свойства state, version, одно из свойств это data с типом "класс", внутри этого класса свойство products с типом "коллекция ваших Item". Следуйте строго структуре, по другому нельзя!

Теперь понятно, но тогда можете пожалуйста подсказать как сделать так, чтобы в студии json код показывался упорядоченным, как когда смотришь его по url ?

И еще почему-то когда я просто пишу responseBody вместо [{responseBody}] , то код не видит что это json , поэтому я так сделал

Если речь про это окно, то Visual Studio не умеет это делать, увы. Знаю Rider умеет, там будет так. Для VS можно попробовать поискать расширение, может есть. Я на вашем месте больше задумывался о том, что вы делаете, а не как удобней посмотреть, ибо весь ваш код можно написать 2-3 строчками. + как я понял, вы HttpClient создаете каждый вызов метода, что не правильно. + JSON.NET не нужен вовсе для этой задачи.

"как сделать так, чтобы ... json код показывался упорядоченным"? Просто смотрите его в Edge или Firefox, они красиво показывают.

С https://catalog.wb.ru/brands/v2/catalog?ab_testing=false&appType=1&brand=27445&curr=rub&dest=-7886569&sort=popular&spp=30& приходит ответ
{
    "state": 0,
    "version": 2,
    "payloadVersion": 2,
    "data": {
        "products": [
            {
                "__sort": 66274,
                "ksort": 517,
                "time1": 2,
                "time2": 38,
                "wh": 206348,
...

Это никак не List<Item>. Нужно сделать что-то вроде
class Product {
    // "__sort": 66274,
    // "ksort": 517,
    // "time1": 2,
    // "time2": 38,
    // "wh": 206348,
    // ...
    // набъёте тут чего надо
}
class Hz {
    public int total { get; set; }
    public List<Product> products { get; set; }
}
class SiteResponce {
    public int state { get; set; }
    public int version { get; set; }
    public int payloadVersion { get; set; }
    public Hz data { get; set; }
}

а потом
var siteResponce = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SiteResponce>(responseBody);


Спасибо, сработало. Даже не подумал, что там может быть другой ответ.
